# Unity PAD system only adds to .abb size

Tags: unity-game-engine, build, assetbundle, addressables

Because my game doesn't fit into 150 mb google play's size limit, i've decided to use "Play Asset Delivery" system. I've created a couple of bundles, set them to "install time" delivery mode, built .abb file and noticed that it is now even bigger than build without bundles.
Looking inside of the file I saw that "base" folder's size didn't even change. Which means that for some reason Unity builds same assets in bundles AND in base module. Which is wrong because separating these assets from base module is the whole point of PAD.
My project doesn't have any "Resources" or "StreamingAssets" folders, so that's not the case. I'm also using Addressables system and refer to the same assets in bundles only by their addresses, so my scenes don't have any direct link to these assets.
What could be missing in this situation?